# find time difference in seconds as an integer with python

Tags: python

I need to find the time difference in seconds with python. I know I can get the difference like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
....
....
....
later = datetime.now()
difference = later-now
```

how do I get difference in total seconds?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
import time
now = time.time()
...
later = time.time()
difference = int(later - now)
```

Comment: This gives an "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'" error in Python3. See Robert Longson's answer.

Comment: @typoerrpr This works fine for me in Python 3 as well.

Comment: `time.time()` returns a float, `datetime.now()` returns a `datetime`.

Answer (score 57):

The total_seconds method will return the difference, including any fractional part.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
...
later = datetime.now()
difference = (later - now).total_seconds()
```

You can convert that to an integer via int() if you want

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'`

Comment: `datetime.now()` returns a `datetime`, `time.time()` returns a float.

Comment: @MichaelMior, you probably used `time.time()` instead of `datetime.now()`

Answer (score 8):

Adding up the terms of the timedelta tuple with adequate multipliers should give you your answer. **`diff.days*24*60*60 + difference.seconds`**

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
...
later = datetime.now()
diff = later-now
diff_in_seconds = diff.days*24*60*60 + diff.seconds
```

The variable 'diff' is a timedelta object that is a tuple of (days, seconds, microseconds) as explained in detail here https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/datetime-timedelta.html. All other units (hours, minutes..) are converted into this format.

```
>> diff = later- now
>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 8526, 689000)
>> diff_in_seconds = diff.days*24*60*60 + diff.seconds
>> diff_in_seconds
>> 8527
```

Another way to look at it would be if instead of later-now (therefore a positive time difference), you instead have a negative time difference (earlier-now), where the time elapsed between the two is still the same as in the earlier example

```
>> diff = earlier-now
>> diff
datetime.timedelta(-1, 77873, 311000)
>> diff_in_seconds = diff.days*24*60*60 + diff.seconds
>> diff_in_seconds
>> -8527
```

Hence, even if we are sure the duration is less than 1 day, it is necessary to take the day term into account, since it is an important term in case of negative time difference.

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is to measure a time span, you may use `time.time()` function which returns seconds since Epoch as a floating point number.

Comment: cool, how do I create a datetime object with the floating point in seconds to print it nicely ?

Comment: Are you talking about time difference or absolute time? The latter can be converted from the raw number of seconds to time struct (with year, month etc fields) with `time.localtime()` or `time.gmtime()` and then either converted to string with `time.asctime()`/``time.strftime()` or used to construct `datetime.datetime` object. I am not sure if there is any function in Python standard library to decompose/print time difference nicely (though this is much easier task than correct representation of absolute time).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to do something like this :

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
now = datetime.now().second
time.sleep(5)
# After 5s
after = datetime.now().second

diff = now - after

print(diff)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).