# Datetime subtraction in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a datetime as below. Voted datetime is the time when user has voted the last time. The user can vote again only after 15 minutes have elapsed

```
current_datetime = 2020-06-27 10:07:29.906931
voted_datetime = 2020-06-25 12:59:56.554216
time_diff = current_datetime - voted_datetime 

which gives the output:
time_diff =  1 day, 21:07:33.352715
```

After getting `time_diff` what I want to do is check if `time_diff` is greater than 15 mins. If `time_diff` is greater than 15 mins then I want to return true else return the remaining time to be 15 mins so that I can pass the remaining time to template and display countdown using javascript. Any suggestions or related articles will be helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking on how to figure out if time_diff is more than 15 minutes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find time difference in seconds as an integer with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638532/find-time-difference-in-seconds-as-an-integer-with-python)

Comment: @12944qwerty yes. If time_diff is not greater than 15 mins then returning the remaining time like (remianing_time = 15 mins - time_diff) so that i can display remaining_time using javascript countdown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have almost everything you need. The only thing left is defining the return value and the conditional statement. I would suggest:

```
def view(request):
    # ... all your logic
    time_diff = current_datetime - voted_datetime
    minutes_to_vote = 0 if time_diff.seconds / 60 > 15 else 15 - time_diff.seconds // 60
    return render(request, 'foo.html', {'minutes_to_vote': minutes_to_vote}
```

Then, in the JS part, you can check if the `minutes_to_vote` equals zero, in which case user can vote. Otherwise, display the countdown you want starting in the `minutes_to_vote` value.

Answer (score 0):

By subtracting 2 datetime objects, you get a timedelta object.
Then, you check if that timedelta is greater than a timedelta of 15 minutes.

```py
import datetime
from time import sleep

voted = datetime.datetime.now() # Example datetime
sleep(3)
current = datetime.datetime.now() # Example datetime
elapsed = current - voted

fifteen = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)

if elapsed >= fifteen:
    return True
else:
    return elapsed
```

Comment: What's the reason behind use `sleep(3)`

Comment: @FurkanSiddiqui I'm just giving an example datetime dates. This means that I just made the datetime object 3 seconds after another. You could change it to 15 or above and it will return True.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import timedelta


def check_time_diff(voted_datetime, current_datetime):
    time_diff = current_datetime - voted_datetime
    return True if time_diff > timedelta(minutes=15) else time_diff.seconds
```